# iOS: Handle noInternet case with Branch.io

Tags: ios, swift, branch, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using Branch pod in my project. When any deep-link is tapped while **no internet**, Branch SDK throws no internet error. I want to retry this activity when the app is back online.

At present, I handled this by holding that userActivity, and once back to online I am calling **continueUserActivity** again. I want to know is there any better way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this on iOS then note that iOS serializes network requests regularly so it does save and retry. Usually it will automatically retry this when the next SDK method is invoked.

Also while generating short link, the SDK makes a network call to our API servers.
When the network is down, we generate a long link which don't require a network call because it is just a concatenation of the base domain (example.app.link) and link data in the form of query params.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the info. So you mean whenever the network is back I should call another function then I will get the previous response

Comment: No, the Branch SDK should reinitialise when network is available though you can also invoke it manually as.per your needs

Comment: No, I have tested this scenario Branch SDK won't reinitialize automatically when the network is back. It reinitializes whenever the application is become active, (Example: Background/ foreground). Please let me know if you have any working code that is happening that way. It will be very helpful